# Neither update_option nor delete_option fires in deactivation hook

Tags: plugins, hooks, options

I have a plugin.  And the following code:

```php
function activate_my_plugin(){
  // my_option value here: 1
  update_option('my_option',0,true); // I've tried with and without last  parameter     
  // my_option value here: 0
}

function deactivate_my_plugin{
  // my_option value here: 1
  delete_option('my_option');
  // my_option value here: 1 
  
  // or

  // my_option value here: 1 
  update_option('my_option',2); 
  // my_option value here: 1
}

function xyz(){
  // my_option value here: 1 or 0
  if(!get_option('my_option')){
    // my_option value here: 1
    update_option('my_option',1);
    // my_option value here: 1
  }
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, __NAMESPACE__ . '\activate_my_plugin');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, __NAMESPACE__ . '\deactivate_my_plugin');

add_action('init','xyz');
```

The deactivation hook is definitely firing, but for some reason, it won't update the option to a new value or delete it.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure you need the `__NAMESPACE__` part within your callback?

Comment: @DeltaG - I think so.  I'm in a namespace, but outside of the class.  But the hook is definitely firing.  I can put other things in the callback, and they happen.  Just the option related functions do not.